# Compile C++ with static lib

Tags: c++, static-linking

this will probably a dumb question for you guy's but I have no experience in C++ what so ever. I'm using an open source project [osrm](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend) (which is awesome). Still to request a route, you have make an http request. To reduce the running time, I would like to build a wrapper around the code and call it using the command line. So I googled a bit and found that osrm already creates a static lib (.a file) when compiling the project. I also found a [piece of code](http://pastebin.com/Dj9E7rkk) that points me in the right directions for building a wrapper. So to begin I build a simple hello world program (see below) that includes some files from that static lib. To compile I followed [this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html) tutorial.
My directory structure looks like this:
./helloWorld.cpp
./libs/libOSRM.a

And the command to compile is this:

```
gcc –static helloworld.cpp –L ./libs –l libOSRM.a
```

The code it selve:

```
#include "Router.h"
#include "boost/filesystem/path.hpp"
#include "ServerPaths.h"
#include "ProgramOptions.h"
#include <InternalDataFacade.h>
#include <viaroute.hpp>
#include <iostream.h>

main()
{
   cout << "Hello World!";
   return 0;
}
```

the exact error I got:

> fatal error: ServerPaths.h: No such file or directory #include "ServerPaths.h"

Comment: When you use the `-lNAME` option, the linker will look for alibrary named `libNAME.a`, so change your option to `-lOSRM` and the library will be found.

Comment: My comment above was just an assumption, because you don't say what your problem is, or if you even *have* a problem. What is your question? Please elaborate!

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I updated my command but still got the same error

Comment: @jorne You should probably add a return type to the `main` ao `int main()` especially since you return 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-IPathToTheHeaderFiles` to the compiler options. So it will find the files to be included. Replace PathToTheHeaderFiles with the path where your file ServPaths.h resides.

*Edit: Add as many `-I` as you need for further header files.*

Additionally it would be worth to read a book about C++ or/and the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Section 3.11 will help.

Comment: thanks, this helped. still now the compiler complaines that includes in that header file can't be found. Any sugestions on that?