# C++ compiler error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This question relates to a [previous answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071892/compile-c-with-static-lib/29072006#29072006). I use an open source project [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) and I want to use it as a lib. So i wrote this small piece of code to test the lib that comes along when you build the osrm project:

```
#include "boost/filesystem/path.hpp"
#include "ServerPaths.h"
#include "ProgramOptions.h"
#include <InternalDataFacade.h>
#include <viaroute.hpp>

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

and used this command to compile it:

```
gcc -std=c++11 -Wall test.cpp -o test -L ./libs -lOSRM -I /home/jorne/Downloads/osrm-backend/Include/osrm/ -I /home/jorne/Downloads/osrm-backend/Util/ -I /home/jorne/Downloads/osrm-backend/Include/ -I /home/jorne/Downloads/osrm-backend/Server/DataStructures/ -I /home/jorne/Downloads/osrm-backend/third_party/ -I /home/jorne/Downloads/osrm-backend/plugins/
```

gcc returned an error message that I posted on [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/73v8egu8).
I now that this probably is an easy/dumb question but I have no experience in c++.

Comment: I think this may have been over hastily closed for the wrong reason - your problem is simply that you invoked the compiler as gcc rather than g++. Change `gcc ...` to `g++ ...` and it should compile.

Comment: tried to change gcc to g++, without success. I'll try my luck on the other page. anyway thanks for pointing this out as well